# How to send push notification in two segments at different times in a day in parse

Tags: javascript, android, parse-platform, push-notification

I am working on android project in which I am using parse cloud for pushing notifications to our customers. We push almost 200000 notification to customers in a day. We are sending a 1000 notifications in a bulk so to send 200000 notifications we have to repeat same process 200 times to control traffic on our web server.

So on parse notification it creates a 200 segments & apart from it we send around 50 thousand different messages to customers at different time in a day so for these it again creating 50 thousands segments on parse push notification dashboard.

Currently it is creating 2500000 segments that made analysis of push notification is getting hard.

We want something like it should have only two segments each day ie first for 200000 notifications and second for 50 thousands notifications.  Is there any way to do this on parse ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using cloud code for sending push notifications. I think thats one way to automate the process. Also you could do something like a cron job like approach to schedule push notifications.

Comment: For such job the easiest way is to write simple daemon, which save state evary 100 segments. It is better then cronjob because you didn't need to estimate how often it should be called. It just read the list and send one after another.